# How to use Sec-Websocket-Extensions in MessageWebsocket upgrade request

Tags: c#, .net, websocket, uwp

I need to use a messagewebsocket, but the documentation says the SetRequestHeader method doesn't support sec-websocket-extensions. The data I need to receive is sent in-whole as a single inbound websocket packet.

The initial http header requires sec-websocket-key and -version values.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The initial http header requires sec-websocket-key and -version values.

For connecting to server by `WebSocket`, the client must send an opening handshake to the server firstly. The `Sec-WebSocket-Key` header field is used in the `WebSocket` opening handshake and it is must be included. Without this field, the [`MessageWebSocket`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.messagewebsocket.aspx)  will not connect server successfully. So actually the `MessageWebSocket` APIs have already setting this field to the header. You don't need to set the request header. You can use Fiddler to grab the get request send by `MessageWebSocket`, and you will see `Set-WebSocket-Key` and `Set-WebSocket-Version` in the header.
[image]

As the `Sec-WebSocket-Key` value of this header field MUST be a nonce consisting of a randomly selected 16-byte and the nonce MUST be selected randomly for each connection, also this header field MUST NOT appear more than once in an HTTP request, so we cannot set this again. But you can set an additionally `Set-WebSocket-Version` by code as follows although I don't think you need doing this.

```
 messageWebSocket.SetRequestHeader("Sec-WebSocket-Verson", "666");
```

Details about the `WebSocket` Protocol please reference [RFC6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#page-57). And more details about how to use `WebSocket` in UWP app please reference the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WebSocket). This sample has both server and client side for testing.

Comment: I still wasn't able to set Version either, but I re-read the spec and I was trying to do too much work. .Net was taking care of all the headers I needed.